# River/Large Stream Sound Design.

Tags: water, foley, video-games

Hey chaps.
In a bit of bother desperately racking my brains, I need to record foley for a game with a small river running through it and it's pretty last minute.
Any ideas or techniques you've used before would be hugely appreciated.
Thanks
Dominic

Comment: @Dominic, I don't understand your question. Are you recording foley or trying to create the sound of a river?

Comment: @jayjennings Sorry bad wording (it's late here) I am trying to create the sound of a river flowing

Answer (score 2):

What kind of game is it? What kind of perspective are we hearing the rivers from?

If you have a contact mic or hydrophone, try recording running water by attaching the mic to a pipe (non-metallic preferably), or some other surface which is in contact with running water. I've recorded some great running water sounds using contact mics, which I imagine would work perfectly in a scenario where the sound was intended to be relatively symbolic (as opposed to trying to recreate a soundscape in a 3D environment).

Comment: @James. It's in the style of skyrim, but on a much smaller scale but that is how it looks and feels. The river is flowing under a bridge that the player walks across.
I think I do have a contact mic somewhere but not used it for some time, I will try and look it out and give it a try.
Thanks!

Comment: @Dominic If there's an immersive 3D environment like Skyrim, I imagine it would be good to have a layer with a bit more 'air' as well, something like a stereo recording of a stream or river. You'll know best of course!

Answer (score 1):

i recently used my shower, tolilet,sink,kettle and hose to record loads of waters sounds for a video game aswell, i did record a small stream and pitch alter and Eq it to give it more size, hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

here is a small river recording i did on my h4n...nothing special but with a bit of post production i think this could be workable sample ;) you can do and use this on whatever you want ;)
http://www.sendspace.com/file/ykaqzd

Comment: @Linas Thanks for the link, it has to be a original recording though. Sorted now.

Answer (score 1):

Not to pimp myself out here, but I do have a large collection or rivers and streams here: http://rabbitearsaudio.com/rea007-brooks-streams-waterfalls/

Comment: @sepulchra thanks alot for link, it had to be a recording though, which i've now done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a Kontakt (Structure?) samples library contains 61 surround streams from waterfalls to rivers and creeks spread from left to right thru the keyboard. Not ready yet but coming out soon.

Comment: @Bernard Sounds excellent, i'm all sorted now though. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

http://soundcloud.com/paulbannister/river-recording